# Why my simple array ={1,2,3} doesn't work in sheets?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I'm using a simple array `={1,2,3}` in sheets and it's not working, I'm getting

> #ERROR! "formula parse error".

But when I use `={1;2;3}` it works well for columns.

I'm from Brazil, and our config of "," and "." is the opposite for numbers interpretation, for example in US we write  US$ 3,000.00 in Brazil we write US$ 3.000,00 I tried to change the language but it didn't work, neither the option ={1.2.3}

Any idea on how to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried ={1\2\3} ?

Answer (score 1):

In your locale try with inverted slashes instead of commas:

```
={1\2\3}
```